# Proxmox not reachable by SSH and web GUI

Tags: ssh, proxmox

I have set up my proxmox environment a few days ago and it was working very well... for 2 days: it suddenly became unreachable from SSH or web GUI.
I still can connect directly on the host.

I have found similar threads on the Proxmox forum but I couln't make it working so far :(
Can someone help me please?

Here are some information in screenshots. Please note:

- In a thread someone asked for the status of the `sshd.device`, but I don't know what it is, and if the cause of the problem would be that it is inactive (dead)
- I had a cyclic error on a custom service: gdrive.service, so a file system failed to create because rclone finds the token should be expired. But `systemctl list-units --failed` did not report errors. So I tried stopping the service and now it displays an error.
  Can it be this file system failure that cause the problem? Or it is more probably a consequence of the network error?

**EDIT**

I just see that my gateway (192.168.1.254) is not reachable from proxmox.
So proxmox seems to be "out of internet"

I can see it in /etc/resolv.conf
But I don't know why I can't access it from proxmox, while I can from my PC

**EDIT 2**

Good news, it's working today!
But this worries me a little bit: why could it be down so long?

[image: ssh services status]

[image: ip a]

[image: network interfaces]

[image: failing services]